# ConTeXt: How to bypass the 12pt setupbodyfont limitation in setuphead

Tags: fontsize, context

It seems to have a `12pt` limitation to `\setupbodyfont` according to [contextgarden](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupbodyfont).

We can bypass this limitation in content and it will work well:

```
\starttext
  \startbuffer[line]
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
  \stopbuffer

  \switchtobodyfont[chorus, 12pt] chorus 12pt: \getbuffer[line] \\
  \switchtobodyfont[chorus, 13pt] chorus 13pt: \getbuffer[line] \\
  \switchtobodyfont[chorus, 14pt] chorus 14pt: \getbuffer[line] \\
  \switchtobodyfont[chorus, 15pt] chorus 15pt: \getbuffer[line] \\
  \switchtobodyfont[chorus, 20pt] chorus 20pt: \getbuffer[line] \\
  \switchtobodyfont[chorus, 32pt] chorus 32pt: \getbuffer[line]
\stoptext
```

[image]

Unfortunately, It does not seems to work this well neither with `textcommand` nor `textstyle` in `\setuphead`:

```
\setuphead[chapter][textcommand={\switchtobodyfont[chorus,12pt]}]

\starttext
  \chapter{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}
\stoptext
```

[image: 12pt]

```
\setuphead[chapter][textcommand={\switchtobodyfont[chorus,13pt]}]

\starttext
  \chapter{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}
\stoptext
```

[image: 13pt]

How can I make it works?

Comment: Try using `textcommand={\groupedcommand{\switchtobodyfont[chorus,13pt]}{}}`

Comment: What do you mean by 12pt limitation? There is no such thing mentioned in the wiki link

Comment: Well, at least the wiki enumerates only 5pt to 12pt: "[...] 5pt ... 12pt". But, yes, "limitation" is probably a too much word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `textstyle`. AFAIK, it is better to define also the proper `bodyfontenvironment`

```
\definebodyfontenvironment [20pt]
\setuphead [chapter] [textstyle={\switchtobodyfont[chorus,20pt]}]

\starttext
\startchapter[title={The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}]
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

Comment: When you use one of the default sizes (e.g. `13pt`) you can preload the typescripts with `\usebodyfont[chorus]` \definebodyfontenvironment is recommended when one uses a non standard fontsize in for the style of a command or environment.